# Is there are way to show vertical line HTML source VS2013?

Tags: html, visual-studio

just I want to ask is there are a way to show vertical line  HTML source in VS2013 to easy visualize what is the starting and ending tags in HTML document 
like

```
<div>
|   <div>
|    |
|    |
|   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an extension to get vertical lines http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30